# Access to iTunes Sound Check Results on iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, volume

I would like to propose to the user some songs whose volume doesn't exceed a certain level. Is there any way to access to the results of the 'Sound Check' option, from the iPhone ?

If not, do you know if I can calculate that with the audio tools in the iPhone SDK ?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to calculate the volume level of a specific song?

Comment: This is exactly what I would like to do!

Comment: @Baldoph have find anything regarding sound check ? cuz i need the same functionality in my app

Comment: @Till do u have any idea then kindly let me know about it